# Type mismatch error in Excel macro

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have this code for work that has a very simple purpose of filling in the hours of regular(A2), overtime(B2), and double OT(C2) work based on the value I input into hours(E2).

I created my macro, attempted to scramble together the correct code (I can correct that later as needed) and now I am receiving a "Mismatch Error" in the highlighted line of code. I have searched several different resources online and just can't seem to figure out what I am missing with this. I have the value of cell E2 defined as a double, and I have a test value (15.7) input into the proper cell (E2), yet it still shows cell E2 as having no value.

Any help is appreciated.

[image: Code]

Comment: Upload your code as text, there is little usage for us having it as an image

Answer (score 1):

`Calculations` is a Worksheet object.

`Worksheets(value)` can be passed a string value, i.e. the name of the worksheet (e.g. `Worksheets("Calculations")`), or an index (e.g. `Worksheets(1)`), but it cannot be passed a worksheet object.

Change all your uses of `Worksheets(Calculations)` to `Worksheets("Calculations")` (e.g. `Worksheets("Calculations").Range("E2").Value`), or bypass the `Worksheets` method entirely and just use `Calculations` (e.g. `Calculations.Range("E2").Value`).

---

Also note that the `ElseIf` portions of your `If` statement won't be processed if an earlier portion of the statement has been evaluated as `True`.  The first part of your statement will execute if `Hours > 8`, so none of the other steps will evaluate unless Hours <= 8.

---

You also have one statement where you use an `And` operator incorrectly.  An `And` operator checks whether the left operand and the right operand are both `True` and, if so, returns `True`, otherwise it returns `False`.  (E.g. a statement such as `If x > 5 And x < 20 Then` would be a sensible way to use it.)  I believe you are trying to use it in order to perform two statements.  The correct syntax to do that would be something like `x = 5 : y = 2`, or just put the two statements on separate lines.

---

I believe the following will do what you are trying to achieve:

```
Sub Calculate
    With Calculations
        hours = .Range("E2").Value
        If hours <= 8 Then
            .Range("A2").Value = hours
            .Range("B2").Value = 0
            .Range("C2").Value = 0
        ElseIf hours <= 12 Then
            .Range("A2").Value = 8
            .Range("B2").Value = hours - 8
            .Range("C2").Value = 0
        Else
            .Range("A2").Value = 8
            .Range("B2").Value = 4
            .Range("C2").Value = hours - 12
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```